# Converting unspecified date to local, then convert to universal, still shows unspecified date

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

```
currentDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(EntryDate, DateTimeKind.Local);
currentDateTime.ToUniversalTime()
```

I pull back EntryDate from our sql server, it is showing 3/29/2017 9:15:00. I debugged and found that the timezone says unspecified. So, when running this code on the server, we are making it the time zone of the server (DateTimeKind.Local).

Then, we want to show this date as the UTC time on our website, so we are passing it back as currentDateTime.ToUniversalTime(). Which should put it at 3/29/2017 01:15:00 (I am in EST). This works just fine when testing on my local build/application.

But when I promote it to the webserver, it shows the time as still being 3/29/2017 9:15.

I have tried all different types of date/time adjustment to manipulate the date, but with zero success.

Comment: `ToUniversalTime` returns a `DateTime` did you assign that to anything?  Remember `DateTime` is immutable.  It should be `currentDateTime = currentDateTime.ToUniversalTime();`

Comment: I'm a little confused, shouldn't the datetime in SQL (9:15) be the UTC time? It would be non-standard to store it as something else. Well, unless it's a datetimeoffset I guess.

Comment: DateTimeKind is not a timezone

Comment: @Greg P - It can solve your problem rather gettting from sql? Now.ToUniversalTime

Comment: Sorry for referring it as a timezone.

Comment: @juharr - I tried that as well..still on the screen it display. What was in the table, displayed on the screen. This is the first thing I tried. This is when I debugged in C# and saw that the Kind was 'Unspecified" not "UTC"...not sure how the database is set up exactly. I am just stating what value I am getting back from calling the database as I am not the DBA

Comment: Well unless you know if the time returned from SQL is UTC or something else how can you ever reliably convert it to another timezone

Comment: We are using that .LocalTime of the server that it displays/saves on...and trying to convert that localtime to UTC...with no luck.

Comment: You're not explaining this very well. Can you absolutely, categorically, without any hesitation tell me if the datetime stored in SQL is UTC? If not, which timezone is it in? If you can't definitely answer this question then this exercise is pointless.

Comment: I can only tell you that when the date gets returned to me, into a class. With the property being set as a datetime. When I do a datetime.Kind, it says unspecified. That is all I have at this point. I will try to get a hold of our sql and confirm/find out. Thank you.

Comment: My point is that unless you know then you can't go any further. It's like asking to convert the word `chat` into Spanish. Well is it the English word for speaking with someone informally, or the French for cat? You can't translate it until you know its origin, so you can't translate a datetime to another timezone without knowing its origin timezone. I assume it's UTC but you need to find out for sure. Good luck.